# Magento 2.2 add to wishlist, how to show child products sku

Tags: wishlist, magento2.2

I have grouped products in my magento 2.2 application, after adding product to add to wishlist. How can i show sku for a child products.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child "simple" product of a configurable by doing something like this in the `Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/column/name.phtml` file (or similar template file):

```
/* @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
$item = $block->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable')
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productRepositoryInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $simpleProduct = $productRepositoryInterface->get($product->getSku());
}
```

(Although you should really not use the `ObjectManager` directly, and should modify the `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info` class via an override or plugin, to get the `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` via dependency injection and create a `getSku()` method to call in the `.pthml` template.)